# Full size assigned right from the start when downloading a file using Indy

Tags: delphi, download, delphi-2010, indy, indy10

I have this delphi code that basically download a file (using **Delphi 2010 + Indy 10.5.8 r4743**), everything works just fine, except that when I download 100Mb (for example), *it seems that* Indy assign the full size (ie. a file with 100MB of dummy content(*) is instantly created), then download the file.

In the end the 100MB is **correctly downloaded**, but since the download process is done in the background using a hidden EXEecutable, I based my code to rely on the temporary file size to **update the main UI**

```
with IdHTTP do
begin
     if FileExists(LocalFile) then
        iLength     := FileSize2(LocalFile)
     else
         iLength    := 0;

     DoExit         := False;
     try
        try
           repeat
                 if ExitApp then
                    Exit;

                 if Not FileExists(LocalFile) then
                    AFileStream     := TFileStream.Create(LocalFile, fmCreate)
                 else
                 begin
                      // File already exist, resume download
                      AFileStream   := TFileStream.Create(LocalFile, fmOpenReadWrite);
                      DoExit        := (AFileStream.Size >= iLength);
                      if (Not DoExit) then
                         AFileStream.Seek(Max(0, AFileStream.Size - 4096), soFromBeginning);
                 end;

                 iRangeEnd          := AFileStream.Size + 50000;

                 if (iRangeEnd < iLength) then
                    Request.Range   := IntToStr(AFileStream.Position) + '-' + IntToStr(iRangeEnd)
                 else
                 begin
                      Request.Range := IntToStr(AFileStream.Position) + '-';
                      DoExit        := True;
                 end;

                 PostTime           := Now;
                 Get(TheURL, AFileStream);
                 IsError            := Not (ResponseCode in [200, 206]);
           until DoExit;

           Disconnect;
        except
              IsError               := True;
        end;    // try/except
     finally
            FreeAndNil(AFileStream);
     end;    // try/finally
end;    // with
```

**My question is** Is there a way to avoid this behavior from indy? I know I can use the OnWork event, but then I will need to keep track of file names.

Ideally, I'd also like to avoid IPC (kinda overkill + I don't want to use that, say every second, for multiple downloads, I very much prefer to use the file size as indication of download progress as it gives more freedom when updating the UI)

(*) I assume it's dummy content since I need between 60-100 seconds on my current internet connection speed to really get the file

Comment: So write a "filename.zip.progress" text file right beside the main file.  :-)

Comment: Yep, that's precisely what I did!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `TIdHTTP` pre-allocates the full file size if it knows the size ahead of time, based on the HTTP response headers.  This is an optimization technique.  Pre-allocating the file avoids unnecessary file system overhead when writing larger files, since the file does not have to keep growing over time, hunting for available sectors on the HDD, slowing down the writing process.  There is currently no way to disable the pre-allocation, it is hard-coded behavior in Indy's internals.  So relying on the file's actual size as a progress indicator will not work for you.  You are going to have to communicate the actual progress information from your background app to the main app.

Comment: Thank you Remy...while I understand the reason behind this decision, this makes pausing/resuming downloads hard (if not impossible) since I wouldn't be able to know the resume byte/offset. I realize this is a different question (derived from the original one) but I wonder if there's a solution for this?

Comment: You would have to use the `OnWork...` events to track the real progress, and then truncate the file on disk to the last known size if the download is interrupted. The only time `TIdHTTP` will not pre-allocate the file is if the data is being sent using the `chunked` transfer encoding, in which case `TIdHTTP` will not be told the file size up front (as the server itself may not even know that). There is already a TODO comment in Indy's source code to make the pre-allocation an optional feature, but there is no ETA on when that will be implemented.

Comment: Thank you Remy, yes that's what I'm doing, I'm looking into writing *.progress files to resume after hard crash, hopefully this will work out for me

Comment: Remy, I [got it working](http://pastebin.com/zeHV5pck) (I'm storing the download info in a database), the only problem is that when resuming (after a crash), `AWorkCount` reflects the current **session byte count**, but it doesn't take in account the previously downloaded bytes (before the app crash).

Comment: Is there a way to get the **total** `download byte position` in the OnWork() event from Indy itself (ie. `TIdHTTP(Sender).CurrentPosition` or something like that)?

Comment: There is no way for `TIdHTTP` to know the previously downloaded size.  Yes, the `OnWork...` events reflect the current session only and always start at 0.  If you are resuming and know where you are resuming from, just add that value to the progress value of the new session.  Otherwise, download your data using a `TStream` and just read the `TStream.Position` property when needed.

Comment: Thank you Remy, I think (hope!) I got it by using `TIdHTTP(ASender).Response.ContentStream.Position` instead of `AWorkCount` in OnWork event, so far I was able to successfully download a file after several hard crashes (again, I still need to test...)

Comment: Depending on what `TIdHTTP` has to do internally to decode the server's data (error reply handling, data de-compressing/de-chunking, HTML parsing, etc), the `Response.ContentStream` may or may not actually point to the `TStream` object you provided to receive the final data. So be careful when accessing the `Response.ContentStream` before its finished. The `OnWork` events are triggered when raw data is read from the socket, not when data is written to the output stream.